# how can i set the default font/size in UML designer?

Tags: uml-designer

how can i set the default font/size in UML designer?
I changed it in the preferences sirius, but the diagram still uses the old default fonts (ubuntu 9) which is just to tiny on my big screen.
i have to change the font manually to 12 for each class/component and to 10 for each operation, property, link etc.

Answer (score 0):

This preference is used only for the Notes. You cannot change the size of the font globally.
But you can select the multiple elements and changes the font size thanks to the Appearance tab in the Properties view.
You can also use the zoom to get all the elements of the diagram in a bigger size.

Comment: Thx for the answer. This is a pain. Zoom is not really a good thing as i anyway see only a few classes. The problem is mainly in Ubuntu as it takes the tiny Ubuntu 9 font. really a bad choice.
Your other hints I know already. As I said this is tedious.... and they should change that in UML designer...

Comment: Feel free to fill an issue on the UML Designer bug tracker describing the enhancement you expect : https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/UML-Designer/issues/new